# Is it true that $G\cong (G/H)\times H$ for every abelian group $G$ and every subgroup $H\le G\;?$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Is it true that $G\cong (G/H)\times H$ for every abelian group $G$ and every subgroup $H\le G\;?$

So I know that by Lagrange's Theorem that $o(H)=o(G/H)= o(G)/o(H)$. I wanted to use a theorem that states that if two groups are cyclic (hence abelian), the order of two groups is equal if and only if they are isomorphic. So now I am stuck, I think that the two groups are isomorphic. Now I'm not sure where to go. I know that $o(H)$ divides $o(G)$. Would it suffice to show that $\big(o(G)/o(H)\big)\times o(H)= o(G)\;?$

Comment: What is the smallest Abelian group $(G, \cdot)$ you know that has a non-trivial subgroup $H$...?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical formulas in your MSE posts. Also, please make the body of your posts self-contained: don't rely on the title to convey important information. As for the mathematics, the statement in your title is false, even if you assume $G$ is cyclic rather than just abelian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: there are two different abelian groups of order $4$, but only one of them can be $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb  Z_2$.

Let  $G$ be the *other* group of order $4$.

$G$ must contain a copy of $\Bbb Z_2$, and then you have $G/\Bbb Z_2 =\Bbb Z_2$ but $G\neq \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$.

What is $G$?

Answer (score 5):

Just because two groups have the same order does not make them isomorphic! Note that $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},$ despite the fact that if $G = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $H = \{0, 2\}$ then $G/H \cong H \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: I made a typo, I meant if two groups are cyclic then they are isomorphic iff they have the same order

Comment: But abelian does not imply cyclic, so I don't know how you would use that in your proof?

Comment: oh I got that mixed up its that all cyclic groups are abelian not all abelian groups are cyclic

Comment: Would it make sense to do two cases? Case one being that G is cyclic and Case two being that G is not cyclic? I'm not sure how I would prove case 2 though

Comment: @Allie: The result is false for cyclic groups unless they have squarefree order. The result is false for general abelian groups unless every element of the group has squarefree order. I'll let you prove those two statements.

Comment: @Arturo We have not learned anything what a square free order is yet, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Allie: These are not tricky terms of art. A number is squarefreee if it is not divisible by the square of any prime.  "Squarefree order" just means the order is a squarefree number.